# JavaScript not works in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter project, where I want to use some js.
I have file with my js:
`<script type='text/javascript' src='/utilities/assets/js/main.js'>` and jquery

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/utilities/assets/js/jquery.js'>
```

The both are availaible from my site, I can look it's content.
I have such code at main.js

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    alert('Javascipt works');
}
```

When I load page, nothing happens.
I tried load javascript class of codeigniter, but when I tried in my view:

```
<?php echo $library_src;?>
<?php echo $script_head;?>
```

It says that that libraries are undefined. How can I use js there?

Comment: `}` is missing `)`, like `})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `);` at the end. The function is never closed.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    alert('Javascipt works');
});
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    alert('Javascipt works');
}
```